# Rails partial is rendering twice?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, renderpartial

I have a table row that is inside a partial.  When I try to render the partial via Ajax - it plops a new table row on top of the table instead of re-rendering the table row I want to update.  Is there a rule with partials and table rows that I'm not following?

The Partial:

```
<div id="edit_the_item_<%= item.id %>">
   <%= render 'edit_item_row', item: item, item_number: item_number %>
</div>
```

Inside the partial:

```
<tr>
    <td>
        <%= item.total %>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Update.js.erb

```
$("#edit_the_item_<%= @item.id %>").html("<%= escape_javascript(render(:partial => 'reports/edit_item_row', :locals => {:item => @item})).html_safe %>");
```

Here is the whole table the partial is in:

```
<table cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <% @items.reverse.each do |item|%>
        <tr>
            <td class="item no_border_left" style="text-align:right;">
                <div id="<%= item.id %>" class="total">
                    <%= number_to_currency(item.total) %>
                </div>
                    <div id="total_form_<%= item.id %>"class="total_form">
                        <%= form_for item, :method => :put, :html => { :class => "theform" }, :remote => true do |f| %>
                        <%= f.hidden_field :report_id, :value => @report.id  %>
                        <%= f.text_field :total, 
                                         :value => item.total,
                                         :size => '6', 
                                         :style => "font-size:1em;text-align:right;", 
                                         :autocomplete => :off,
                                         :class => 'form_send',
                                         :id => "total_field_#{item.id}" %>
                        <% end %>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <div id="edit_the_item_<%= item.id %>">
            <%= render 'edit_item_row', item: item %>
        </div>
    <% end %>
</table>
```

**UPDATE**

So it looks like you can't have a partial made of table rows and table cells, and re-render the partial and except it to work seamlessly, it looks like the tags get messed up.

I had to put my partial inside a TD like this:

```
<tr>
    <td>
        <div class="123<%= item.id %>">
            <%= render 'edit_item_row', item: item %>
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

And then inside the partial, I put a whole table, like this:

```
<table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="4" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                <%= form_for item do |f|%>
                    <%= f.hidden_field :report_id, :value => @report.id %>
                    <tr class="highlite grid edit_item_<%= item.id %>">
                        <td>
                        </td>
                        <td <%= item.notes? ? "style=border-bottom:none;" : "" %>>

                            <%= f.text_field :name, :style => "font-size:1em;width:234px;margin-right:20px;", :value => item.name, :id => "first_focus_#{item.id}" %>

                            <%= f.select :tax_id, Tax.all.collect{ |c| [c.territory_short_form, c.id]}, {:selected => item.tax_id}, :style => 'font-size:1em;'  %>  
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <%= collection_select(:item, :job_id, @jobs, :id, :name, {:selected => item.job_id}, :style => 'font-size:1em;')%>                      


                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <%= f.text_field :deduction, :style => 'width:44px;font-size:1em;text-align:right;'  %>

                        </td>
                        <td style="width:80px;text-align:right;">

                        </td>
                        <td style="width:80px;text-align:right;">
                            <%= f.text_field :tax_override, :style => "font-size:1.1em;width:70px;text-align:right;" %>

                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <%= f.text_field :unclaimed_tax, :style => "font-size:1.1em;width:70px;text-align:right;" %>

                        </td>
                        <td style="text-align:right;">
                            <%= number_to_currency(item.cost) %>
                        </td>
                        <td style="text-align:center;">
                            <%= f.text_field :total, :style => 'width:60px;font-size:1em;text-align:right;'  %>

                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="highlite grid edit_item_<%= item.id %>">
                        <td colspan="7">
                            Notes:
                            <%= f.text_field :notes, :style => "width:600px;font-size:1em;" %>
                        </td>
                        <td colspan="3" style="border-top:none;">
                            <div class="delete" style="float:right;">
                                <%= link_to 'Delete', item_path(item), :method => 'delete', :confirm => "Are you sure?" %>
                            </div>
                            <div style="float:left;">
                                <%= f.submit 'Update', :style => 'font-size:1em;'%>
                            </div>
                            <div class="f_left" style="margin-left:80px;margin-top:4px;">
                                <%= link_to 'Cancel', '#', :data => { 'item-id' => "#{item.id}" }, :class => 'clicky', :onclick => "$('.original').show();$('.item_#{item.id}').show();$('.edit_item_#{item.id}').hide();return false;"  %>
                            </div>

                        </td>

                    </tr>

                <% end %>
</table>
```

Now everything works?! Shrug.

Comment: What happens if you replace the `escape_javascript(render(:partial => 'reports/edit_item_row', :locals => {:item => @item})).html_safe` part with `foobar`? Does it replace the table row or does it add on?

Comment: Are you 100% sure that nothing else on the page has id set to `edit_the_item_<item id>`?  Perhaps you are not changing `item.id` between a loop, etc?

Comment: For sure no other names, I did a project wide search, and it's only in those two places.  I've slimmed down my table to see if I was missing a tr tag or something, but it's still doing it - I've added the whole table to my post.

Comment: Looks like you can't have partials made up of TR's and be able to re-render them.  I had to render a whole table for it to work.

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery's `.replaceWith()` instead of `.html()`. The former replaces the element as well, while the latter just replaces the contents.

See: http://api.jquery.com/html/#html2 vs http://api.jquery.com/replaceWith/

Comment: This still isn't working for me, - it's still putting it on top, but I'm going to give this solution another shot tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

Apologies about not remebering the excat details but when I previouly had this problem is was enviromental.  That is is happend in development but not in production (Heroku).  May be something to do with config/envoronments/development.  Pierre